# Pretty faces redirect to root

Tags: prettyfaces, jsf-2.3

I'm using pretty faces 3.4.4.
I want to redirect pages with following url:

```
www.domain.com/overview/overview.xhtml?target=my_param
```

to

```
www.domain.com/my_param
```

To achieve this I use this setting:

```
<url-mapping id="overview">
    <pattern value="/#{target}" />
    <view-id value="/overview/overview.xhtml"/>
</url-mapping>
```

which is working. But the issue is, that all the standard pages in root like `aboutus`, `home` and `contact` are not working any more! The content of this pages is overwritten with the content of the `my_param` page.

Can any one help to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll likely need to change the order of your rules in the `<pretty-config>` file. They are matched in order, and the issue here is that your mapping pattern is very general, and will match ALL possible pages at the top level of your domain:

```
<pattern value="/#{target}" />
```

To fix this, you need to add mappings for your other top-level pages, and they need to be above your general rule for handling "my_param" redirects:

```
<url-mapping id="home">
    <pattern value="/home" />
    <view-id value="/home/home.xhtml"/>
</url-mapping>

<url-mapping id="contact">
    <pattern value="/contact" />
    <view-id value="/contact/contact.xhtml"/>
</url-mapping>

<url-mapping id="overview">
    <pattern value="/#{target}" />
    <view-id value="/overview/overview.xhtml"/>
</url-mapping>
```

You haven't posted how you are issuing the redirect, which you said is working, but if you wanted to do that using PrettyFaces, you'd use something like this config:

```
<rewrite match="/overview/overview.xhtml?.*\btarget=(\w+)\b" substitute="/$1/" redirect="301" />
```

Though I would probably use [OCPsoft Rewrite](https://www.ocpsoft.org/rewrite/) for this type of redirect instead, since you can make much more declarative & safe rules. (PrettyFaces is now built on Rewrite)